# Wrong email content is sent during user activation

Tags: emails

When admin blocks or unblocks (activates) a user account a different email body is sent to the user from that which exists in admin/config/people/accounts page. The site is multilingual (two languages) and this is happening only for the original language, its translation is working correctly. I tried by clearing the cache, changing the user language even searching in modules and core files but I was not able to find anything.

Is there a different location/setting that overrides the people/accounts page? Also I have multiple use roles but this is happening for all the user roles. I attach screenshot of the settings. Even if I could find the row in the database that holds the message sent would be useful.

[image]

Comment: This was also posted at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3309098

Comment: It was deleted from drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3309098 so the issue remains open

Comment: It was not deleted, but postponed, because Drupal 8 is end of life and unsupported on Drupal.org. But I noticed someone reported a similar issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3309880

Comment: @cliefen ok thanks for this, I m new here